# Removing line breaks that start with a \ in VB Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi I currently have the following lines in VB code and I would like them to go from:
[image]

Remove the link break and the \

AB/1234A,024/2/010/003,Y,SIG,443,10.11.186.10,10503,255.255.255.248,10.11.186.9

I know to use the replace with regular expression I just can't work out the fields?

Comment: What is a line break with starts with a backslash?

Comment: What fields are you talking about?

Comment: Apologies when I pasted the text it removed the slash I've added a picture now for clarification

Comment: maybe you need to escape the \ with a \

Answer (score 1):

- Select the \ AND the line break
- **Select** > **Select All Occurrences**
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>